# Check for URL variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that takes a date variable:  mypage.php?date=2015-07-14 and displays output.

How do I check if the date= is empty and if it is then insert and refresh the page with the current date?

I've tried to formulate a small script at the top of the page using _GET with the date value but am not sure how to handle the reload of the page?

Comment: Have you tried something? Wrote some pseudo code or did some research ?

Comment: Updated what I've tried so far @Rizier123

Comment: Then add your small script to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check your input is not empty using [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function, and create a [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (it will default to current, unless you pass parameter), and passed it as get parameter in [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to the same page.

```
if(empty($_GET['date']))
    header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?date='.date('Y-m-d'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the empty language construct from PHP to check if a date was supplied: http://php.net/empty

Then you could use the header-function to redirect if no date was entered in the url: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

For example:

```
<?php

if (empty($_GET['date'])) {
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?date=' . date('Y-m-d'));
}
```

Also note that any headers should be sent before generating any output in your script.

Answer (score 1):

What you seek is a combination of [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) functions with redirect using [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). The end result could look something like this

```
<?php    
$rawDate = isset($_GET['date']) && !empty($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : false;

$requestDateTime = $rawDate ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $rawDate) : false;
$currentDateTime = new \DateTime();

// If datetime from GET is invalid or is not current date...
if (!$requestDateTime || $currentDateTime->diff($requestDateTime)->days > 0) {
    // Redirect to current page with current date
    header(sprintf('Location: ?date=%s', $currentDateTime->format('Y-m-d')));
}
```